# How to fix "Uncaught Error: Invariant failed" react-router-dom error in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react website up and running on the web host, I am trying to add `react router` to it, so I installed `react-router-dom` using `npm`, but I get this error without further explanation about the error message or anything.

I tried changing `react-router-dom` to `react-router` which is the old version but I got different errors so I returned to react-router-dom.

```
// src/Container3d.js 
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Scene3d from './Scene3d'
import Model2 from './Model2'

class Container3d extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container3d">
          <Route path="/model-1" component={Scene3d} />
          <Route path="/model-2" component={Model2} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Container3d

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// src/App.js 
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/model-1">model-1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/model-2">model-2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The error message:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:198 Error: Invariant failed
    at invariant (tiny-invariant.esm.js:9)
    at react-router-dom.js:154
    at Tg (react-dom.production.min.js:184)
    at bi (react-dom.production.min.js:232)
    at ci (react-dom.production.min.js:233)
    at Di (react-dom.production.min.js:249)
    at Yh (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Xh (react-dom.production.min.js:245)
    at qf (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at Ji (react-dom.production.min.js:253)
qh @ react-dom.production.min.js:198


react-dom.production.min.js:248 Uncaught Error: Invariant failed
    at invariant (tiny-invariant.esm.js:9)
    at react-router-dom.js:154
    at Tg (react-dom.production.min.js:184)
    at bi (react-dom.production.min.js:232)
    at ci (react-dom.production.min.js:233)
    at Di (react-dom.production.min.js:249)
    at Yh (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Xh (react-dom.production.min.js:245)
    at qf (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at Ji (react-dom.production.min.js:253)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wrap your `App` component with `BrowserRouter`. 
Look at the below code.

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/model-1">model-1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/model-2">model-2</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Here I have created small demo for you!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-sbhdpk

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: thank you so much, and yes it worked, you saved the day :)